# Is it correct to use the default Django package as an app?

Tags: python, django

When creating a project in Django, I get this structure:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
```

Is it correct to add `view.py`, `forms.py`, `models.py`, etc., inside the inner directory `mysite`? I have seen they use it as default but they create a new app for that which already contains some extra files.

Comment: What do you mean *"correct"*? It will *work*, but it's unconventional; why don't you want to create an app?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know it will work, "correct" in the way if it is the best practice to do. Why is it unconventional in that way?

Comment: It is a convention from Django's news blogs origin. The default folder is where all the urls get routed. The other apps would be different news websites with a single backend.

Comment: Anyone who works with your code in the future will be expecting things to be in their own app. It makes things more modular.

Comment: See e.g. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/reusable-apps/